# Using "acpi=off" in a virtual machine

Tags: kernel, virtual-machine, acpi, kernel-parameters

Does using the kernel command-line option `acpi=off` in a virtual machine (i.e VirtualBox 5.2) make sense when the host OS has been booted with ACPI **on** ?

I mean for debuging purposes if someone wants to disable ACPI , is it a good idea to use VBox or (s)he has to boot it as the main OS ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A virtual machine has its own virtual ACPI implementation: it is not directly connected to the ACPI of the host. A VM's ACPI implementation is likely to be relatively minimalist and straightforward, and most virtualization hosts should have pretty much got it right by now, so the question is: what is the actual problem you're trying to solve with `acpi=off`?

In most cases, disabling ACPI is overkill as a permanent fix: a sort of "my mobile phone charger started smoking, so I turned the house main circuit breaker off and have been living without mains electricity ever since".

Back in late 1990s and early 2000s when ACPI was a new thing and Linux's support of it was still work in progress, it might have been good advice. But now, the ACPI Component Architecture (ACPICA), which forms the base of operating-system-side ACPI code in Linux, Haiku and FreeBSD, actually is a *reference implementation* of ACPI support in operating systems. If the ACPI implementation in the system firmware is so bad you need to resort to a permanent `acpi=off`, it must be *really bad indeed*.